# window.parent.location.replace(document.URLUnencoded) in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe, exception

I was going through an Asp.net project file.
In that they are navigating to a htm page when session got expired or session variable is null or empty like this

```
if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Expired.htm");
        }
```

in that htm. in onload function following piece of javascript is there

```
function SessionExp()
            {         
                if(window.parent.length > 0) 
                {
                    window.parent.location.replace(document.URLUnencoded);                   
                }      
             }
```

what is **window.parent.length**,**document.URLUnencoded** means and sometimes document.URLUnencoded reurns Nan, what is it means?.

Note: Iframes are used.

Anyone Pls explain this....

Comment: It can't find your `Expired.htm` page. if you use `Response.Redirect("Expired.htm");`, make sure they are on the same level/folder. Else, navigate to that folder `Response.Redirect("Folder1/Folder2/Expired.htm");` The same applies to iFrames.

Comment: @jmc:what is window.parent.length,document.URLUnencoded means and sometimes document.URLUnencoded reurns Nan, what is the meaning of that one?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `URLUnencoded` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534709%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a non-standard, Internet Explorer specific property. You cannot use it from any other browser. [The `location.href` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/href) should return the value you need.